# change content dynamically based on url - angular 4

Tags: angular, url, dynamic, angular-routing

I have a url like this https://test.com/subject/21

In the page I have form fields. One of the form field is subject code. Now I want subject code to be filled dynamically with number in the url.

User can change the number in the url, and that should change the content in the page.

[image]

```
<input formControlName="subject_code" value="" placeholder="Subject Code" class="form-control>
```

I have the routing for the page like this:

app.routing.module.ts

```
 {
    path: 'subject/:code',
    component: SubjectComponent,
    loadChildren: './subject/subject.module#SubjectModule'
  },
```

Let me know if additional info is needed. Thanks!

Comment: why a downvote? it would be helpful if someone gives explanation to their downvote instead of simply giving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ActivatedRoute`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'subject',
  template: `
    <input formControlName="subject_code" [(ngModel)]="code" ngplaceholder="Subject Code" class="form-control>
  `,
})
export class SubjectComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  code: number;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.code = 0;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.code = +params['code'];

       // In a real app: dispatch action to load the details here.
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```